# APC UPS-5000 Power off remote servers

Tags: remote, ups

I have a UPS connected via the serial port to a server using PowerChute Business Edition. If a power outage occurs I would like this server to start shutting down all other servers within the network.

Is there dedicated software to do this? I was thinking of creating a command file which runs a .bat file to run shut down commands to each server (using PSExec). I can set PowerChute to run this command file when a power failure occurs.

Is there not anything APC provide which has this functionality and is more efficient than writing a .bat file to do this?

Thanks,

Comment: If you don't mind getting away from APC software you'll find that the APCUPSd software in "master / slave mode" will do what you're looking for. Have a look: http://http://www.apcupsd.com

Answer (score 2):

Yes - you're already running it, you just haven't installed or configured all the pieces. Install the PowerChute agent on the other machines that you want shutdown by the server, the one that is attached via serial to your UPS.

Edit - you know what? I think you're right, given the scenario that you have. If you had a management NIC for the SmartUPS, you can do this with the PCBE server and agent. With only serial communication, you can't do this easily and have to do what you're doing, managing your own scripts.

Comment: Is that possible? The PowerChute software facilitates communication with the APC that the server is connected to, not to other servers that aren't connected to the APC. For that you would need a network management card in the APC unit and then you would install PowerChute on all of the other servers and configure them to communicate with the APC unit. No? http://www.apc.com/resource/include/techspec_index.cfm?base_sku=ap9630

Comment: Read up on Powerchute Business Edition. The network cards for the SmartUPS are nice and obviate the need to have a serial cable and a server for that purpose. If you don't have the network card in your UPS, you run the PCBE Server on the machine with the serial connection, and the agent on the other machines that you want to shut down.

Comment: Dammit - Joe, I think that you're right. To do this easily, you do need the NIC. To do this the long way, you can do what Vishal was thinking of doing, with your own scripts.

Comment: @mfinni: Yep-- you need the grossly overpriced NIC to do what Joe is talking about.

Comment: $300 is grossly overpriced? By comparison, how much is an iLo card? Because it's not just a NIC, it's a management controller.

Comment: @mfinni: Have you looked at the hardware on the APC management cards? It might be $25.00 of components. It galls me that APC charges so much for these cards on top of their inflated UPS pricing. It reminds me of, back in the day, when they would pin their serial cables in a proprietary manner so they could make a buck selling overpriced serial cables. I like what the APC NICs do, but they should cost more like $150.00.